# jQuery - Use a variable as a function parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to use dynamic variable as a dynamic javascript function parameter. But it's giving error as variable not defined.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'get_category_list.php',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success: function (data) {
        var i = 1;
        $.each(data, function() {
            var id = this.id;
            //console.log(id);
            var edit = "<img src='../../dist/img/icon/edit.png' " +
            "style='border: 1px solid #999637; " +
            "border-radius: 2px' " +
            "title='Edit' " +
            "onclick='show_edit_form(id)'>";
            catTable.row.add([
                i++,
                this.name,
                this.level,
                this.create_date,
                edit
            ] ).draw();
        });
    }
});
```

Please tell me what is the exact problem here?

Comment: If you at least told us what the problem is, and what line it's on, we would know where to start ?

Comment: Which variable? Which error?

Comment: The exact problem is that your problem is not clear

Comment: I think is here: `show_edit_form(edit)`

Comment: Instead of declaring, initialising and incrementing an `i` yourself, you can (should) just use `$.each(data, function(i) { …`

Comment: @LucasCosta Ya because regarding posted code, `edit` is local, not global BUT this code doesn't really make sense anyway

Comment: And of course, why would you pass a string representation of an element to it's own event handler, when you can get the actual element with just `this`. On the other hand, why not create a real element with `createElement` and use `addEventListener` ?

Comment: Use `this` if you want to refer to the image element. `edit` is not in scope of the inline handler, and also it's just a string. But better use `$(…).on('click', function(e) { … })` anyway

Comment: @A.Wolff, I'm confuse too, it's a guess.

Comment: I'm confused three, period !

Comment: when i click on image (var edit), it shows me 'id'(parameter variable) is not defined,

Answer (score 1):

I guess the error occurs in `show_edit_form` function. You have to pass something there, in your care it's

```
 var edit = "<img src='../../dist/img/icon/edit.png' " +
            ...
            "onclick='show_edit_form(" + this.id + ")'>";
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code below, you passed `edit` as argument of `show_edit_form()`:

```
var edit = "<img src='../../dist/img/icon/edit.png' " +
           "style='border: 1px solid #999637; " +
           "border-radius: 2px' " +
           "title='Edit' " +
           "onclick='show_edit_form(edit)'>";
                                    ^^^^
```

Perhaps your intention was to pass the element itself as the argument. But your code won't do, it couldn't even access the `edit` variable inline its definition. The simplest solution is **leaving the argument field blank**. Because you could already access it using `this` when handling the click event.

On the other hand, as others have pointed out on the comments, it's better to use [**jQuery**'s `.click()`](https://api.jquery.com/click/) method.

---